# How can I specify which container when the elements are generated in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying a list of messages group by sender.

I'm also displaying a form after each group of messages so that I can reply to that particular sender.

```
<% @grouped_messages.each do |sender, messages| %>

 <% messages.each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg.content %></p>
 <% end %>

 <div class="reply-container", id='reply-container'>
 <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
 <% end %>
 </div>

 <%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', id: 'reply-link' %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to show the form only when the 'Reply' link is clicked.

```
$(".reply-link").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#reply-container').toggle();
 $('#reply-link').toggle();
});
```

This doesn't work as there can only be one id on the page and all the reply-container's have the same id.

How can I specify which container to hide when the elements are dynamically generated in a loop?

Comment: Is this some interview question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411712/how-to-identify-hash-elements-in-a-loop-when-using-jquery/21412010#21412010

Comment: What do you mean interview? I'm working on a project

Comment: I meant I answered almost identical answer yesterday so it looks like it might be part of some company interview process. :) It would be ok if it was, just curiosity question.

Comment: No before I was trying to add an element. Now Im trying to toggle a form. I suck at javascript so I need a lot of help.

Comment: Ah, that was you then! Sorry, didn't notice that. :) My question for now: why do you have both form submit button and additional reply link?

Comment: I have lots of messages on a page and only want to show the reply form when they click on the reply link. Otherwise the form is too cluttered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
$(".reply-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest( '.reply-container').toggle();
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

and you can remove ids: "reply-link" and "reply-container"

edit: 
but you can make it better:

```
 <div class="reply-container", id="reply-sender-#{sender.id}-container">
 <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
 <% end %>
 </div>

 <%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', id: "reply-sender-#{sender.id}" %>
```

and then it could look like:

```
$(".reply-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-container").toggle();
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the reply-container doesn't appear. The reply link disappears though. I have checked the reply-container spelling and everything seems ok. It doesn't seem to be finding the closest element

Comment: I now get the error: TypeError: this.attr is not a function
$(this.attr("id") + "-container").toggle();

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".reply-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('.reply-container').toggle();
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Edit:

You should also separate groups into divs:

```
<% @grouped_messages.each do |sender, messages| %>
 <div class='message_group'>

   <% messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p><%= msg.content %></p>
   <% end %>

   <div class="reply-container", id='reply-container'>
   <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
   <% end %>
   </div>

   <%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', id: 'reply-link' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but they all appear and disappear